# How to make spotfire unmark/uncheck all filters either as an action or script

Tags: spotfire

I have a dashboard with a lot of filters and I would like the user to have the options of removing all filters (all filters unchecked). I can't find the option, and I can see others are talking about ironpython?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this:

1) In the filter panel itself (if you are showing that to users) there is a "Reset All Visible Filters" button in the upper right.

2) Edit -> Reset All Filters (ctrl+r)

3) Create a text area, "Insert Action Control", Actions -> Functions -> Reset All Filters

4) Ironpython method: https://community.tibco.com/questions/can-iron-python-be-used-reset-filters-specific-table-and-then-also-navigate-different-page

Comment: Thanks but these methods only reset my filters, I want them to be un-checked?

I havetried this iron pyhton script:
https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-uncheck-all-checked-values-all-visible-checkbox-filters-tibco-spotfire-using-ironpython

But this only allows me to uncheck one filter at a time..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with a button as Andrew Pruet described in no 3 above.  Note that in Spotfire 10 and higher, all of the shortcut keys have been deprecated.  Ctrl R won't work anymore.